# Delphi: How can I read the windows dns cache directly?

Tags: delphi

I know I can use "ipconfig /displaydns" and Powershell's "Show-DnsServerCache" 
and get the output from that commands, but I want to do it directly. I have found source code in stackoverflow on how to do it in C but I can't translate that to delphi.

Does anyone know how to do this in delphi? I couldn't find anything in google.

Thanks in advance.

(this is my first post and also English is not my mother tongue, sorry if I'm not clear)

The code I found:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _DNS_CACHE_ENTRY {
    struct _DNS_CACHE_ENTRY* pNext; // Pointer to next entry
    PWSTR pszName; // DNS Record Name
    unsigned short wType; // DNS Record Type
    unsigned short wDataLength; // Not referenced
    unsigned long dwFlags; // DNS Record Flags
} DNSCACHEENTRY, *PDNSCACHEENTRY;


typedef int(WINAPI *DNS_GET_CACHE_DATA_TABLE)(PDNSCACHEENTRY);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    PDNSCACHEENTRY pEntry = (PDNSCACHEENTRY)malloc(sizeof(DNSCACHEENTRY));

    // Loading DLL
    HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("DNSAPI.dll"));

    // Get function address
    DNS_GET_CACHE_DATA_TABLE DnsGetCacheDataTable =
        (DNS_GET_CACHE_DATA_TABLE)GetProcAddress(hLib, "DnsGetCacheDataTable");

    int stat = DnsGetCacheDataTable(pEntry);
    printf("stat = %d\n", stat);
    pEntry = pEntry->pNext;
    while(pEntry) {
        wprintf(L"%s : %d\n", (pEntry->pszName), (pEntry->wType));
        pEntry = pEntry->pNext;
    }
    free(pEntry);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We aren't a translation service. You need to make more effort. A very basic primer in C and you'll manage fine. Don't give up so readily.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a translation service

Comment: If you've got no experience in C it might look like Chinese and you simply have no clue where to start. A response like you need to make more effort isn't exactly helpful.

Comment: I am with David on this. You will come across C a lot so it is worth taking a primer course, and you should be able to do this yourself. There are some good ones on line I am sure. If you are not prepared to do that you need to hire someone who can do it for you.

Comment: Also note that `DnsGetCacheDataTable` seems to be undocumented

Comment: It seems fair to close the question and to open a new one asking for help on specific parts of the translation and show your efforts then @JuanK

Comment: @Remko It will only look like Chinese because no effort has been made to learn the basic syntax. If you've mastered one language it won't take long to learn enough C to read that code. Asker does indeed need to make more effort.